# NFS Mouting Failing due to illegal port

Tags: networking, debian, nfs, opnsense

I have a VM machine that has a public IP interface and a private IP interface. The private interface is assigned 192.168.50.78. Then I have a dedicated host that acts as my "router" using private IP 192.168.50.1 and this is, therefore, my gateway for my 192.168.50.0/24 local network. The "router" I have is OPNsense.

That being said, I am trying to mount within my VM to my two remote NFS servers. The mount fails because of an illegal port coming from my VM, which is behind NAT:

```
[root@NFSHOST ~]# tail -f /var/log/messages | grep "rpc.mountd"
Feb 21 22:31:40 NFSHOS rpc.mountd[28721]: refused mount request from 197.189.XXX.ZZZ for /data/secondary (/data/secondary): illegal port 33744
Feb 21 22:35:22 NFSHOS rpc.mountd[28721]: refused mount request from 197.189.XXX.ZZZ for /data/secondary (/data/secondary): illegal port 40085
```

And this is due to port translation happening. A solution is to add `insecure` to my `/etc/export` file, which I have tested and can confirm does indeed work.

However, as it suggests, it `insecure` and highly not recommended. I have tried adding a port forwarding rule on OPNsense and for some reason, it remains to fail with illegal ports.

[image]

Is there anyway I can solve this issue, PS I cannot use "bridge" mode either I need to set some sort of rule in OPNsense to handle this accordingly and I am not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to finally solve this specific issue. I was told here: [OPNsense Link](https://forum.opnsense.org/index.php?topic=32603.msg157722#msg157722)

The following:

> IIRC NFS servers expect the source ports coming from clients to be
> under 1024 to be considered secure. Make sure you check the
> "Static-port" on your NAT outbound rule to prevent the firewall from
> modifying the source port on TCP and UDP packets.

I ended up adding a NAT outbound rule on OPNsense for the entire local LAN with static port enabled, and it solved the issue. I can now mount NFS via secure port ranges.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the server did not support older protocol version. You can either force a client to use other version like this:

```
mount -o vers=3 -t nfs 123:/
```

This applies to standard linux client of course. If you can not influence a client like this check this post how to have other protocol support in server side:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/974696/how-can-i-make-the-nfs-server-support-protocol-version-2-in-ubuntu-17-10